# C++ Matrix and Vector Multiplication Seg faults when trying to store them into a summation

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to compute a Jacobi iteration by following the pseudocode I found on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_method). I have run my code through gdb and I find that I have a heap-buffer-overflow whenever I try to compute the sum of my Matrix and vector being multiplied together.

Here is my code:

```
std::vector<double> sol(std::vector<double> &x,std::vector<std::vector<double> > &A, std::vector<double> &b, int n)
{

    double sum; 
    int counter = n;
    while(counter != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
        {
            sum = 0.0;
            for (int j = 1; j <= n; ++j)
            {
                if(j != i)
                {
                    sum += A[i][j]*x[j]; //Issue seems to be here in GDB
                    std::cout << "Sum " << sum << std::endl;
                }
            }
            x[i] = (1.0/A[i][i])*(b[i]-sum);
            for(auto&& e : x)
            {
                std::cout << e << " ";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        counter--;
    }

    return x;
}


int main()
{

    //const int SIZE = 1000;
    const int SIZE = 2;

    double ranNumber = 0.0;
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > A;
    std::vector<double> testX = {1.0,1.0}; 
    std::vector<double> testB = {11.0,13.0};


    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    {
        std::vector<double> k;
        for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j)
        {
            ranNumber = randNumber();
            k.emplace_back(ranNumber);
        }
        A.emplace_back(k);
    }

    A[0][0] = 2.0;
    A[0][1] = 1.0;
    A[1][0] = 5.0;
    A[1][1] = 7.0;

    std::vector<double> xSol = sol(testX,A,testB,30);

    for(auto &&e:xSol)
    {
        std::cout << e << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

According to the wiki, I should receive the answer 7.1111, -3.2222, I think I have followed the pseudocode except for the `k` part because I am not quite sure how to implement that into a vector.

What is causing the segmentation fault? Am I going out of bounds in my vector or Matrix? That is what leads me to think I am seg faulting but I am not sure exactly what is going on here. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT: I should clarify, yes, this is a terrible way to have a vector of vectors implemented. This is just a test to see if I can replicate what they have on Wikipedia. If I can get this answer, I will remove the unnecessary A[0][0]...etc. I have a random number function that will generate the numbers for me. But this is just to make sure this is working correctly.

Comment: Explanations on why people are down voting will be appreciated.

Comment: in C/C++ indexing of arrays starts from `0`

Comment: @SemyonBurov, I have tried changing the for loop to start `int i = 0; i < n; ++i)`, but the same segfault error occurs in the same place. I maybe should have altered the code to what it looks like now, but it currently segfaults as well.

Comment: Always best to show the correct-est code you can. Otherwise you will primary receive comments and answers on the stuff you know is wrong, not to mention down and close votes from folks who think you should have just read the text book a whole lot better.

Comment: Well, the size of your arrays is clearly `2`, `2x2`, `2`. Why do you loop for `n = 30`?

Comment: Next, when hunting a segfault a question should contain complete code (a [mcve]) that demonstrates the segfault. Your question suggests you have have located the failure point with a debugger. Use the backtrace and step commands to try to isolate the problem further. When something dies deep in a vector typically, almost always, the problem is in some code you wrote and the backtrace can be very helpful in determining where you really went wrong.

Comment: @SemyonBurov according to the wiki, and again I’m not sure about this, in the input section there is an input for convergence. I assumed this input to be n. However, now that I’m thinking about it I am going out of bounds in my original matrix and vector. N should be the size of my vector.

Comment: @Sailanarmo -- You wouldn't be going out of bounds if you used `vector::size()` to limit the loop instead of using another variable, `n`,  that knows nothing about the vectors.  By doing this, you've gone back to  `C`-like programming, where the number of entries is passed.  No need for that using `std::vector` -- Introducing extraneous variables to denote the size instead of using what vector gives you , i.e. `vector::size()`, you risk making mistakes like this.

Comment: @user4581301 you are correct, I should have thought about that instead of posting this abomination of code. I just wanted to create the verifiable segfault exactly how I was implementing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have the indexing issue from 0 to `n-1` instead of 1 to `n`.

Then you construct in main your vector A being 2 x 2, but you iterate throug `A[i][j]`, j going until `30`. So you access the array out of bounds !  Call the function using `SIZE` because you construct the matrix based on `SIZE`.

Finally, you divide by `A[i][i]` without first ensuring that it's not a divide by zero. (Ok it's not, but you should verify as a kind of reflex).

I don't know if you'll get the correct answer, but you should no longer experience short dumps.